# Javascript Code Won't Run

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have written the following in Javascript however, the I am failing to get the variables to use the calculate function properly. I do not think the code is asking to recall the correct variables/functions and subsequently isn't working. Could anyone identify where this needs to be changed, or a simpler method of using the calculations?

Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Parallel RLC Circuit Parameters Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form onreset="myfunction()" align="center">

        <font face="Garamond">

            <h1 style="color:#ff336f">Parallel RLC Circuit Parameters Calculator </h1>

            <p style="color:#92E367"> Please Enter the Voltage Supply:
            <input id="Supply Voltage" value=0> V</input><br>
            </p>

            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter the Frequency:
                <input id="Frequency" value=0> Hz</input><br>
            </p>


            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter the Resistor Value:
                <input id="Resistance" value=0> Ohms</input><br>
            </p>


            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter the Inductor Value:
                <input id="Inductance" value=0> H</input><br>
            </p>


            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter the Capacitor Value:
                <input id="Capacitance" value=0> F</input><br>
            </p>


            <button id="Submit" type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>


            <button id="Reset" type="button" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

            <p style="color: #808080" id="message">The values  will appear here after clicking Calculate</p>

    </form>

<script>

    function calculate() {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<br>";
    var Vs = document.getElementById('Supply Voltage').value;
    var f = document.getElementById('Frequency').value;
    var R = document.getElementById('Resistance').value;
    var L = document.getElementById('Inductance').value;
    var C = document.getElementById('Capacitance').value;
    const pi = 3.14159265;

    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "" + "<br>";

    if ((Vs||f||R||L||C)==0) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Zero values are not permitted.     Please reset the form.";
            break;
        }

var Xl = calcXl(f,L,pi);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Xl = " + Xl +" Ohms  <br>";

var Xc = calcXc(f,C,pi);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Xc = " + Xc +" Ohms  <br>";

var Z = calcZ(Xl,Xc,R);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Z = " + Z +" Ohms    <br>";

var Ir = calcIr(Vs,R);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Ir = " + Ir +" Amps  <br>";

var Il = calcIl(Vs,Xl);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Il = " + Il +" Amps  <br>";

var Ic = calcIc(Vs,Xc);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Ic = " + Ic +" Amps  <br>";

var Is = calcIs(Ir,Il,Ic);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Is = " + Is +" Amps  <br>";

var G = calcG(R);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="G = " + G +" Seconds <br>";

var Bl = calcBl(Xl);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Bl = " + Bl +" Seconds <br>";

var Bc = calcBc(Xc);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Bc = " + Bc +" Seconds <br>";

var Y = calcY(Z);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Y = " + Y +" Seconds <br>";

var phi = calc_phi(G,Y);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="phi = " + phi +" Degrees <br>";

var f_res = calc_f_res(pi,L,C);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="f_res = " + f_res +" Hz <br>";

var f_res = calc_f_res(pi,L,C);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="f_res = " + f_res +" Hz <br>";

var Q = calcQ(R,C,L);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Q = " + Q +"<br>";

var Bw = calcBw(f_res,Q);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Bw = " + Bw +"<br>";

}

function calcXl(f,L,pi){
return 2*pi*f*L;
}

function calcXc(f,C,pi){
return 1/(2*pi*f*C);
}

function calcZ(Xl,Xc,R){
return 1/(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((1/R),2)+Math.pow((1/Xc)-(1/Xl),2));
}

function calcIr(Vs,R){
return Vs/R;
}

function calcIl(Vs,Xl){
return Vs/Xl;
}

function calcIc(Vs,Xc){
return Vs/Xc;
}

function calcIs(Ir,Il,Ic){
return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ir,2)+Math.pow((Il-Ic),2));
}

function calcG(R){
return 1/R;
}

function calcBl(Xl){
return 1/Xl;
}

function calcBc(Xc){
return 1/Xc;
}

function calcY(Z){
return 1/Z;
}

function calc_phi(G,Y) {
return Math.acos(G/Y);
}

function calc_f_res(pi,L,C) {
return 1/(2*pi*(Math.sqrt(L*C)));
}  

function calcQ(R,C,L) {
return R*(Math.sqrt(C/L));
}

function calcBw(f_res,Q) {
return f_res/Q;
}

function  myfunction() {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "The value of the resistor will appear here after clicking calculate"
    }

     </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: replaced your `break` with `return` and fixed a semicolon at a place

Comment: @mehulmpt Please do not modify an author's code in a question. The errors you fix are exactly the point of asking that people try to address by answering.

Answer (score 0):

use a return, not a break statement.

```
if ((Vs||f||R||L||C)==0) {
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Zero values are not permitted.     Please reset the form.";
        return;
    }
```

In calcZ you're missing a paren

```
function calcZ(Xl,Xc,R){
  return 1/(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((1/R),2)+Math.pow((1/Xc)-(1/Xl),2))); //extra paren added at the end.
}
```

got it working for me.

HEre's the codepen I used to test: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YLYRNZ?editors=1010

Comment: Great thanks for your help. However, it is only returning the BW as a calculation. The answers to all my other variables/calculations are not appearing, do you know why this may be?

Comment: You're overwriting the content of message element each time. use '+=' intead of "="